# How do I automatically email my MailChimp subscribers after I publish a post on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, email, mailchimp

So I need to notify my subscribers every time I publish a post on my WordPress blog.
I know MailChimp offers RSS-driven campaigns, but:
1. I need to send email right after the post is published
2. I need my emails to include thumbnail image from WordPress post
I've read MailChimp RSS to email tutorial and it seems like RSS-driven campaigns don't provide the functionality I need. Is there any plugin or some other way to send emails automatically when I update my blog?